# Use listView.MultiSelectChoiceModeListener on Android API < 11

Tags: android, listview, multi-select

Is there a way to enable batch contextual actions in a ListView on Android API level below 11? The contextual ActionBar works fine with ActionBarSherlock.

Or do I need to do a custom implementation? (I'am a IT-Human, I want the easiest way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work without a custom implementation.